# Pandas: filling a fixed number of new columns with dataframe structured with the same fixed number of repetitions

Tags: python, pandas

first I apologize for the title but this was hard to formulate.

I have a `DataFrame` which looks like:

```
I | A   | B
--+-----+----
x | xA1 | xB1
x | xA2 | xB2
x | xA3 | xB3
y | yA1 | yB1
y | yA2 | yB2
y | xA3 | yB3
z | zA1 | zB1
z | zA2 | zB2
z | zA3 | zB3
...etc
```

Where `I` is the index and `A` and `B` are the columns.
The `Dataframe` always have the same number of repeated index, 3.

I would like to have only one index and three times more columns with the corresponding values, something like:

```
I | A1  | A2  | A3  | B1  | B2  | B3  |
--+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
x | xA1 | xA2 | xA3 | xB1 | xB2 | xB3
...etc
```

The `DataFrame` is really big in my project, so iterating with `iterrows` to fill manually the second one is too slow to be used, is there a fast(er) way to do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably try pivoting the dataframe. I think you'd have to throw another column in to make it work though (and you'll end up with a multiIndex for your columns)

```
df['idx_level'] = list(range(0,3)) * (df.shape[0] / 3)
pivoted_df = df.pivot(index = None, columns = 'idx_level')
```

You could crush the multiIndex down to a single level pretty easily if you need.

Comment: It works, thanks a lot! Pivot sometimes give me headache trying to figure out how to achieve what I want.